# Finding difference between sets of data

Tags: bash, shell

There are two files with list of names, one name per line. I need to find what names from the second list aren't in the first. Is there some clever way to do it using shell and not "real" programming language?

P.S. I did the comparison using Ruby, but still curious.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$ grep -vf file1 file2
```

or:

```
$ comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: For files of any appreciable size, you will find that your first option will suck in a spectacular fashion.  Further, if the files are large and you might conceivably run this comparison more than once, you should sort the input into new files, rather than doing the sort every time you run comm.